# Upload file using @FeignClient in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I have two apps, both are on SpringBoot. I'm trying to upload file from one app to another using `@FeignClient`

Here is Controller code that accepts file upload

```java
@PostMapping(
    path = "/result/output/{resultId}",
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Result uploadOutputProviderMetadata(@PathVariable(value = "resultId") UUID resultId,
                                           @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    return resultService.storeResult(providerSearchTaskId, getString(multipartFile));
}
```

Here is the test snippet call for this controller

```java
new MockMultipartFile(
                "file",
                file.getName(),
                "application/zip",
                FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
var resultAsString = getMockMvc()
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .multipart("/private/api/v1/result/output/" + resultId.toString(), getPort())
                        .file(multipartFile)
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString();
```

Test works, MvcMock can upload file using `MockMultipartFile` and `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`

Here is my poor FeignClient from another app that tries to upload file

```scala
@FeignClient(name = "Client", url = "${server.url}")
trait UploadClient {
  @PostMapping(
    path = Array("/private/api/v1/result/output/{resultId}"),
    consumes = Array(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
def uploadResult(@PathVariable resultId: UUID,
                   @RequestPart(name = "file") file: MultiValueMap[String, Object]): Result
  }
}



@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(clients = Array(classOf[UploadClient]))
class FeignActivationConfiguration {

  @Bean
  def clientFeignEncoder(messageConverters: ObjectFactory[HttpMessageConverters]): Encoder = {
    new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters))
  }
}
```

I have e2e test and feign throws

```
status 400 reading AdsManagerClient#uploadResult(UUID,MultiValueMap)
feign.FeignException$BadRequest: status 400 reading UploadClient#uploadResult(UUID,MultiValueMap)
```

Why?

I've added error decoder, controller wasn't very informative

```scala
// Error response code: 400, responseText: ERROR, reason: null 

val errorMessage = s"Error response code: ${response.status()}, responseText: $responseText, reason: ${response.reason()} while calling  $methodKey"
```